# How to Compare and get the values two Array of objects?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have two Array of objects as follows.

Array of object 1 ---->    `[{locationId:1,locationName:"Bangalore"},{locationId:2, locationName:"Mumbai"}]`
Array of object 2 ----->   `[{baseId:1,baseUnit:"abc"},{baseId:2,baseUnit:""}]`

Is there any short method where I can locationName from first Array, using baseId from Array 2 and push that to new Array of objects,in angular 6. I dont want to use for loop.

Comment: could you post the desired result as JSON?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a = [{locationId:1,locationName:"Bangalore"},{locationId:2, locationName:"Mumbai"}];
    var b = [{baseId:1,baseUnit:"abc"},{baseId:2,baseUnit:""}]
    var c = [];

a.map(obj => {
  b.map(res => {
    if (obj.locationId == res.baseId) {
      c.push({
        "locationName": obj.locationName,
        "baseUnit": res.baseUnit
      });
    }
  });
});


console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code should do what you need (comments in code)

```
// Go throught first array
newArray = array1.map(location => {
    // Look for corresponding object in second array based on Ids
    const foundBase = array2.find(base => base.baseId === location.locationId);
    // If the object is found, return combined object
    if(foundBase){
        return Object.assign(location, foundBase);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

### Reduce your arrays

Here you can see that it is possible to use `.reduce` on an `Array` to iterate over the array whilst generating a new one:

```
let array1 = [{locationId:1,locationName:"Bangalore"},{locationId:2, locationName:"Mumbai"}]
let array2 = [{baseId:1,baseUnit:"abc"},{baseId:2,baseUnit:""}]

// Combine objects in array
array1.reduce((newArray, _, index) => newArray.concat({...array1[index], ...array2[index]}), [])
```